# Closed image of locally compact space

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is locally compact and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous closed and surjective, must $Y$ be locally compact? This seems like it should be relatively simply to answer, but I am unable to find either a proof or a counterexample. Any ideas?

Comment: Is $X$ assumed to be Hausdorff?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that $f$ is also assumed continuous?  Otherwise a counterexample (inspired by the recently deleted answer) would be given by $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb Q$, $f(x)=x$ for $x$ rational, $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational.  (A trivial counterexample if Hausdorff isn't assumed comes from letting $X$ be an indiscrete space.)

Comment: Yes, lets add continuity. That rules out indiscrete spaces since the only way $f $ can be continuous if $X$ has the trivial topology is if $Y$ also has the trivial topology.

Comment: If you leave out Hausdorffness for $X$ you need to define what you mean by "locally compact", as the various definitions are not equivalent in this case.

Comment: $X$ is locally compact if for each $x\in X$ there is a compact $K\subset X$ such that $x$ is in the interior of $K$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

First note that $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact.

Consider the quotient space $Y = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{N}$  (i.e., identifying all natural numbers to a point $*$).  Note that the quotient mapping $f : \mathbb{R} \to Y$ is closed (and continuous).  (This essentially follows because we are identifying a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$.)

**Claim:** $Y$ is not locally compact.

*proof:* If $U$ is a neighbourhood of $*$, we may without loss of generality assume that it is of the form $$U = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} ( (n-\varepsilon_n , n + \varepsilon_n ) \setminus \{ n \} ) \cup \{ * \},$$ where $\varepsilon_n < \frac{1}{4}$ for all $n$.  It follows that $$\overline{U} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} ( [n-\varepsilon_n , n + \varepsilon_n ] \setminus \{ n \} ) \cup \{ * \}.$$
For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$ define the open set $V_m$ to be $$\left( \bigcup_{n < m} ( ( n - \varepsilon_n - \frac{1}{4} , n + \varepsilon_n + \frac{1}{4} ) \setminus \{ n \} ) \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{n > M} ( (n-\varepsilon_n , n + \varepsilon_n ) \setminus \{ n \} ) \right) \cup \{ * \}.$$  It is clear that $\{ V_m : m \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is an open cover of $\overline{U}$, however it has no finite subcover, and so $\overline{U}$ is not compact.  $\Box$

Comment: Note that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty ( (n-\frac{1}{n} , n+\frac{1}{n} ) \setminus \{ n \} ) \cup \{ * \}$ is a neighbourhood of $*$ that is disjoint from $\{ n + \frac{1}{n} : n \geq 1 \}$.  (Or a simple modification depending on what your $\mathbb{N}$ is.)