# Question about a closed mapping.

Tags: general-topology

We just learned about quotient mappings and various properties of the quotient topology. I'm curious about metrizability under these mappings. Namely, if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a closed continuous surjection and $X$ is metrizable, does it follow that $Y$ is metrizable?

Comment: Does this work as a counterexample? Take $X$ to be a union of two lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the induced metric and topology; map it onto the line with the origin doubled, which is not normal and hence not metrizable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I don't think this map is closed.  If we write $X = \mathbb{R}^2 \times \{a,b\}$, then $[0,1] \times \{a\}$ is closed, but its image $[0,1] \times \{a\}$ is not closed in the quotient, since it fails to contain its limit point $(0,b)$.

Comment: @Nate: Okay; I thought there was something amiss, but couldn't figure out what. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118005/8348) provides a counterexample.  Basically, the space $Y$ described there fails to be first countable.

**Fact:** $*$ does not have a countable base in $Y$.

*proof:*  If $\{ U_i : i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a family of open neighbourhoods of $*$ in $Y$, then without loss of generality we may assume that each is of the form:
$$ U_i = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ( (n - \varepsilon_{i,n} , n + \varepsilon_{i,n} ) \setminus \{ n \} ) \cup \{ * \}.$$
We may also assume that $\varepsilon_{i,n} \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $i,n$.

For each $i \in \mathbb{N}$ define $\delta_i = \min \{ \frac{\epsilon_{i,n}}{2} : n \leq i \}$.  Now define $$V = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ( ( n - \delta_n , n + \delta_n ) \setminus \{ n \} ) \cup \{ * \}.$$

Given $i \in \mathbb{N}$, since $\delta_i < \varepsilon_{i,i}$, it follows that $U_i \not\subseteq V$.  $\Box$

Comment: Yes, nice example. Also as an addition: closed continuous maps do preserve paracompactness and if we add that all points have compact preimages (so we have a perfect map: closed continuous as well) then we do preserve metrisability and the example shows that even one non-compact preimages is already enough to spoil it.

Comment: You can simplify this a bit by letting $X=\omega\times[0,1]$ and taking $Y$ to be the quotient obtained by identifying the points $\langle n,0\rangle$ to get the hedgehog of spininess $\omega$. Or for a truly minimal skeleton, $X=\omega\times(\omega+1)$ and $Y$ is the quotient obtained by identifying the points $\langle n,\omega\rangle$.

Comment: @Brian: I'm confused.  Hedgehogs are metrizable, so how would this give an example of a closed quotient mapping from a metrizable space onto a non-metrizable one?

Comment: @Brian: I think I understand.  You meant for the other question, and essentially using the same proof.  Yeah, your space is (quite) a bit easier to visualise.

Comment: @Arthur: Sorry: I shouldn’t have called it the hedgehog space. I forgot that that term is usually reserved for the metrizable version rather than quotient.

Comment: @Brian:  Wow!  Was I confused!  Contained in my rambling was a "proof" of 0=1.  Yes, the "non-metrizable hedgehog" space works quite nicely in both situations.  Thanks.