# Quotient of a locally compact space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, quotient-spaces

I am looking for an example of a quotient of a locally compact space that isn't locally compact.

Is there a not too complicated example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$X=\mathbb{R}$, and identify the integers to a point. The resulting quotient map is an example.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118018/4280) you can see the proof of the fact that the quotient is not locally compact, and it is also noted that this quotient map is even closed.